# WPF datagrid show data of all columns in one row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

In datagrid I want to show list which is grouped, there is a style for datagrid row to show expander which shows basic information and then user has to expand to see more data (in terms of another datagrid). What I want to do in the expander is to aggregate the data of one column from the nested datagrid as part of basic information.

What is the best way to do it? Do I do it by making my ViewModel arrange the data for parent datagrid and bind that property? Or I can do it solely in XAML?

Comment: aggregate the information in your vm and bind to it, sounds easier

Comment: Yeap thats what I did "making my ViewModel arrange the data for parent datagrid and bind that property"